# Incorrectly ran chmod 754

Tags: permissions, chmod

I accidentally ran the following command: `sudo chmod 754 opencv` instead of `sudo chmod 754 home/mrman/opencv`

Now I can't access the folder which contains all the OpenCV files without being root. Furthermore, when I navigate to the folder, it has become an (executable) file? Please, how can I restore the folder?

[image: folder which has become a file after chmod 754]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That command only will change 1 file named "opencv". It would make sense for it to be a folder and if so ...

```
chmod 775 opencv
```

should restore it.

Then again: your image is showing "opencv-3.0.0-alpha". That command you used ("chmod 754 opencv") does NOT change that filename; it would only change something actually named "opencv".

So is that all you did? or did you do more?

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. Yes I only ran `sudo chmod 754 opencv` and then the folder "opencv-3.0.0-alpha" changed. I do not understand that either.  Running `chmod 775 opencv` changed "opencv-3.0.0-alpha"  back to  a directory.

Comment: you might have added a * behind it? or pressed "tab"? (so it would expand?)

Comment: Ah , perhaps I did a tab yes.

Comment: In case you want to know: type "history|grep chmod" in command line. It might list what you typed.

Comment: Thanks again! It gives me this `1995  sudo chmod 754 opencv` Not sure whether I did the extra tab or not. Come to think of it, I'm pretty sure I didn't...

Comment: Looks like you removed others' execute permission from the *containing directory* `$HOME/opencv`. As an aside - IMHO you shouldn't be using `sudo` at all inside your `Home` folder.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. But how can I actually get  ownership of the `$HOME/opencv` directory.